# Gradle tries to reach remote repository even though jars are in Maven local

Tags: jenkins, gradle, serenity-bdd

Background: I'm working on a Jenkins box that has no internet access (on the command line browsers work idk why) trying to run a Serenity Gradle script(a fluffy version of this http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_building_serenity_projects_in_gradle). I had this problem on my local machine I was able to resolve it by manually creating a .m2 (downloading jars 1 by one on the browser) and having mavenLocal in the list of repository (as in the example).

Problem: so I copy the .m2 folder to the Jenkins user on the remote box but when running the command Gradle clean test aggregate on the Jenkins box the output says the error is a failure to reach jcenter.

Things I've tried:
1 running with --offline (result says no cache version of artificat)
2 copying the Gradle cache from my local to the Jenkins user on the remote box.( They have a shared folder) Why is it trying to reach when the 
3 copy the .gradle folder from one to another. 
4 remove jcenter (still fails)

I'm at a lost as to what could possibly be wrong in our project Jenkins anywhere we've been tinkering for over a week

Comment: Copying caches around is not the best idea you ever had I hope. Or to say it the other way around, it is a really bad idea that will most probably not work. Copying over the `.m2` folder should probably have worked, **if** you put it to the right place and the building user has access to the location. Run the build with `-i` or if not enough `-d` to see what's going on and where it looks for the local maven repository. And last but not least, if your browser can access internet, but Gradle cannot, you have to use a proxy to access internet. The Userguide tells you how to configure a proxy.

Comment: The condescending commentary wasn't a necessary opening the .m2 folder is in. {JenkinsUser}/.m2/repository in the debug log files it specifically says: No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: C:\Users\{JenkinsUser}\.m2\repository.  it then proceeds to say loading file from said repository for all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this sort of problem would probably be to set up a Nexus or Artifactory proxy that your Jenkins box can access directly (the Nexus/Artifactory installation needs to be on a box with internet access, though).

Comment: We considered that but the people in charge of setting this up for us(we don't have the access to do so) are dragging their feet.  Could you think of a reason it's trying to reach out even though the jars already in mavenLocal. That's what's confusing me. On my local doing that fixed it.